# How to unhide/show the 'Activity Bar' on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally hid the Activity Bar of VS Code.
How can I make it visible again?

I checked the 'View' menu bar options but couldn't find an option for the task. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 45):

Go to **View=>Appearance=>Show Activity Bar**
as of latest version

```
Version: 1.41.0
Date: 2019-12-11T18:32:17.711Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-72-generic snap
```

[image]

Answer (score 24):

You can make a shortcut to hide and unhide the activity bar.

1. Open the Command Pallete (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on macOS) and then type `Keyboard Shortcuts`
   [image]
2. Click on `Toggle Activity Bar Visibility`, and choose your shortcut using keyboard!
   [image]

After doing this, you can now use your shortcut key.

Answer (score 13):

I know of 3 ways to show/hide it.

- View -> Appearance -> Show Activity Bar
- Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on macOS) -> Toggle Activity Bar
- settings.json -> `"workbench.activityBar.visible": false`

I also made a Youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jskbY0fnjeU) demonstrating all three ways.

Answer (score 3):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on macOS
2. Type "view: Toggle Activity Bar Visibility" (Intellisense should come in handy).
3. Enter

Voila!!

Answer (score 3):

Use this shortcut (Windows)

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

to toggle Activity Bar

Answer (score 2):

My Bad!! The option is available within 'View' navigation bar.

Goto 'View' navigation bar. Then goto 'Appearance' option, select 'Show Activity Bar'

Comment: This must have changed, "appearance" is not part of "view". But you can go to setting and search for "activity", here you'll have the checkbox that allow to show/hide it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command for this called View: Toggle Activity Bar Visibility that you can use from the command pallet(F1)

Answer (score 0):

Step:1
Open the VS Code

Step:2
Click the "view" option on the top bar.

Step:3
Click the "Appearance" option at View.

Step:4
Click the "Show Activity Bar" option at Appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to show and hide activity bar in VS code

Comment: Ctr+b is for showing/hiding sidebar

Comment: that is what i too answered

Answer (score 0):

you can open the `settings.json` by opening the settings, selecting the icon for `open settings(JSON)`, scroll to the bottom and if you just hid it you will see `"workbench.statusBar.visible": false`. Just delete the `workbench.statusBar.visible` line and save.

Answer (score 0):

The setting is called `workbench.activityBar.location` now.

```
Version: 1.84.2 (Universal)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:52:33.687Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.1.0
```