# Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, command

I installed, desinstalled and installed again the Visual Studio Code and in may computer it can`t appear the bar in the Y axix in left side of the screem. Someone can help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMxOs.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Unhide/make-visible the 'activity bar' on visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613307/how-to-unhide-make-visible-the-activity-bar-on-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, at the top menu, go to View -> Appearance -> Show Activity Bar. This will toggle the menu you're looking for.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much ZackWolf.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Could you please mark this answer as the solution? That way others who have this issue will know where to look.