# How can I show VS Code's disappeared extensions and files sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I was working I don't know where I clicked, but then the Extensions and Files sidebar disappeared.

[image]

Comment: I think you are referring to the [Activity Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_activity-bar)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Unhide/make-visible the 'activity bar' on visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613307/how-to-unhide-make-visible-the-activity-bar-on-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *View* -> *Appeareance* and then reenable the Activity Bar by setting a checkmark there.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

View > Appearance > Show Activity Bar.

Another way is by clicking on Customize Layout right next to the Minimize Button, and then click on Activity Bar to make it visible